# Cordova Websocket

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, websocket

I am trying to learn using websockets in my app with ionic this one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-websocket and I copied the example below:

```
var ws = new WebSocket('ws://echo.websocket.org');

$scope.sendMessage = function(){
    ws.send('test');
};

ws.onopen = function () { alert('open'); };
ws.onmessage = function (event) { 
    alert(event.data);    
};
ws.onerror = function () { alert('error occurred!'); };
ws.onclose = function (event) { alert('close code=' + event.code); };
```

It seems to be ok, but when the connection is down how can I reconnect and how can I make this disponible for all my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be looking into [Google Messaging Service](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) (or Firebase Messaging Service) so you don't have to worry about disconnections. The thing with sockets, Cordova and Android, it won't work if your app goes into the background (the network connections are stopped) so it renders the whole thing useless.

Comment: the question is how to use websockets, not using the state controlled Google Firebase paid solution

Comment: I totally disagree. It really depends what the application is doing on web sockets or what higher level protocols play on it. Suppose, you have a chat, would you lose all messages when you don't pay attention to your mobile? If you would, I would feel the application is useless, but it definitively could run on web sockets. It's a matter of creative data management, how to fetch all messages when getting back to audience